# Remove certain part of a batch of filenames

Tags: powershell, file-rename

I have over 15.000 files with this kind of name: `YYYYgaYYMMDD.*` and I 'd like to remove "gaYY". The result would be: `YYYYMMDD.*`.

Example: `2017ga171008.bmp` should become `20171008.bmp`.

I started with:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\location |
    Rename-Item -NewName { ($_.Name -replace ... }
```

and that's where I'm stuck.

Comment: `-replace 'ga\d\d'`

Comment: Thanks to Ansgar and wp78de! Great help!